# prevent the text shown from hideing after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, bottle

Here is little code I am trying to run, the problem is that it is displayed for a second instead of to be shown permanently.I talk about the numbers in

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

how can I fix it?

```js
 function myFunction() {
        var s = document.getElementById("myText").value;

        var password = ""
        for (var i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
            var firstletter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            password = password + "" + firstletter;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "your password is:" + password;
    }
```

```html
<h1>how many numbers</h1>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
    
      
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
   
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the length of string **BUT** You gave the string.
Loop should be `(var i = 1; i <= s.length; i++)`

```html
<h1>how many numbers</h1>
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var s = document.getElementById("myText").value;

        var password = ""
        for (var i = 1; i <= s.length; i++) {
            var firstletter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            password = password + "" + firstletter;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "your password is:" + password;
    }     
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: why s.split('').length and not s.length ?

Comment: The Password is showing perfectly. Your question is not clear

Comment: this hasnt fixed the problame, but thank you so muck for your help!

Comment: Do you want to hide it after few sec?

Comment: ok i will explain, the code is ok, my problame is that if you try to run the code the output will show fot a second and then disappir. try yourself to run the code (even the fixed one that you have sent) and see that he disappirs after a few secondes

Comment: No dude, Its working perfectly, I left it for 1 hour, It didn't disappear, Still If you have problem, Share your `Team-viewer Credentials` Privately.